# Julia DSP Periodograms n > nfft is error, why?

Tags: julia, signal-processing

This

```
n = length(s)
# n = 25920169
nfft = 8192
noverlap = Int64(floor(nfft/2))
window = hanning(nfft)
#sp = spectrogram(s, n, noverlap; nfft=nfft, fs=1, window=window)
sp = periodogram(s; nfft=nfft, fs=1, window=window)
```

throws the error

```
nfft must be >= n
```

But the documentation says:

```
If length(s) < nfft, then the input is padded with zeros.
```

Doesn't it mean that nfft < n should be correct?

Comment: `Int64(floor(nfft/2))` are three operations, float division, followed by float rounding, followed by Int conversion. Instead use integer division, `div(nfft, 2)`, directly. Furthermore, rounding to Int should be done directly: `floor(Int, x)` instead of `Int(floor(x))`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the FFT length `nfft` should be greater than the signal length `n` to prevent aliasing.

The `periodogram` function uses FFT internally, where the length is denoted as `nfft`. In theory, when using FFT, the signal in both time domain and frequency domain are discrete and periodic, where the period is given by `nfft`. So, if you specify an `nfft` that is less than the signal length `n`, this actually introduces aliasing in the time domain to make the signal periodic with `nfft`.

For example, if you have a sequence `1 2 3 4 5`, assuming that your period is also `5`, you have

```
1 2 3 4 5
          1 2 3 4 5
                    1 2 3 4 5
--------------------------------
      ... 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

i.e., the original sequence. Now assume you have a period of `3`, then it looks like

```
1 2 3 4 5
      1 2 3 4 5
            1 2 3 4 5
------------------------
  ... 5 7 3 ...
```

When you take FFT of this sequence with `n > nfft`, you are working with this aliased sequence.

You can manually allow for `n > nfft` by applying the `wrap(x,nfft)` as bellow and feeding its output to `periodogram`, MATLAB does exactly that.

```
function wrap(x,nfft)
    y = zeros(eltype(x),nfft)
    for (i,xi) in enumerate(x)
        y[mod1(i,nfft)] += xi
    end
    y
end
```

For example:

```
wrap(1:5,3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 7
 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I thought periodogram performs a Welch transform. With (s, nfft, noverlap; nfft=nfft, fs=1, window=window) it wokrs.